# Which Path should i take when making a 2D iPhone game?

Tags: iphone

I have been looking into Open GL ES, Quartz 2D, a framework called cocos2D and I am not sure what would be the best direction to move forward in when making a 2D game. I am planning on making a pretty simple not to intense game and I am new to game development but not to iphone development.

Which would be the easiest to learn? Which one would give the best performance ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the same position as you and I chose Cocos2D. It's perfect for a beginner. It's basically a wrapper for OpenGL ES, and it's open-source so you can see how it works and modify it to your liking.

Starting with Cocos2D is a good idea because you can make a lot of abstraction from complex low-level functionality, while achieving a good high-level overview of your game. While developing, you will pick up some low-level details as well, so that you'll be more prepared for them in future games.

Plus, Cocos2D has a really nice structure for simple 2D games. If you were to write this yourself in say OpenGL ES, then you would just lose a lot of time that you could be spending actually designing your game :)

But that's just my opinion.

Oh and don't worry too much about performance. Cocos2D is fine in that aspect. Like I said, it works on top of OpenGL ES so the drawing is done very efficiently. It also supports stuff like sprite batching and texture atlasses, which is good for performance.

Answer (score 0):

As the goal of these frameworks is to provide simplified game development, this is definitely the way to go. Of those that you list, two of them are graphics "engines" (Open GL ES, Quartz 2D), and one is a game engine (cocos2D). If you choose graphics, then you'll probably have to write quite a bit of extra code, even for a simple game.